# What files does ypdomainname change on rhel8 / centos8?

Tags: linux

When I run `ypdomainname somedomain`, it clearly takes effect, because `ypdomainname` will show the state changed, before and after. I need to deploy this change via configuration management, and can't find an ansible module to do it, so the solution will likely be to use `lineinfile` or something similar to deploy the change; only problem is: I can't find what files on the filesystem it changes. What files does it change?

The man page mentions `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` but these remain unchanged, so I think the man page is inaccurate or incomplete.

When I create a filesystem snapshot before and after, I find no differences in `/etc` or any other changes that I think seem relevant. Perhaps I'm missing something...

When I run `strace ypdomainname somedomain`, it shows that it does not access any files; it calls the `setdomainname()` function from `libc`. This is documented here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setdomainname.2.html which unfortunately seems to offer no information about what it actually does.

Answer (score 2):

The first hint is that strace doesn't actually show libc functions – it shows *kernel syscalls*. (They only happen to have similar names.) For historical reasons, the YP/NIS domain name is stored by the kernel (alongside the hostname), and although the NIS client software runs in userspace, it always gets the domain name from kernel.

So the 'ypdomainname' command indeed does not access any files – its purpose is not to make permanent changes, but rather to upload the domain name **from** /etc to the transient kernel memory, and it uses a dedicated kernel syscall to make that happen.

Permanent storage for the domain name is indeed a file in /etc, but you have to change it using a regular text editor and *then* run 'ypdomainname' to upload that change to the currently running kernel (which is also done on every reboot). Different distributions store the YP/NIS domain name in different locations; `/etc/domainname` is one option, but it might also be in /etc/sysconfig or /etc/defaults.

But fortunately for you, the kernel also exposes the YP/NIS domain name as an ordinary sysctl – `kernel.domainname` – which you can set through the virtual /proc/sys/kernel/domainname path for the running system, as well as through /etc/sysctl.d to make the change permanent, in a distro-independent manner. Ansible even appears to have a dedicated [sysctl](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/sysctl_module.html) module for making such changes:

```
- sysctl:
    name: "kernel.domainname"
    value: "example"
    sysctl_set: yes
```

Comment: Thanks, you nailed it.  :-)  Add this: For RHEL/Centos 6, 7, and 8 (and probably older versions), `echo "NISDOMAIN=whatever" >> /etc/sysconfig/network` and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`domainname`, `ypdomainname`, and `nisdomainname` return whatever value is set in RAM for the kernel parameter `kernel.domainname`. Calling, for example, `domainname mydomain` sets that variable to `mydomain` and does not save it to disk. Run `sysctl -a` for a full listing of kernel parameters.

There are two separate routes to get this to persist this across reboots:

1. `echo 'kernel.domainname=mydomain' >> /etc/sysctl.d/99-nisdomain.conf`

This is a more widely-compatible option because it relies on the more ubiquitous `sysctl` program to load values from these files. All that needs to happen to load the values at bootup is some process calling `sysctl --system` which every Linux distro I know of does.

2. `echo 'NISDOMAIN=mydomain' >> /etc/sysconfig/network`

`/etc/sysconfig/network` can also be used to set the host name as well as a few other options.

This is reliant on systemd-based init systems.